# How make full width video screen of video

Tags: video, video-editor

[image]

1. photo
   show my video who is not full in width,can I make somehow my video is like 2. photo, full width video screen without empy space left and right?

Comment: If you're asking if you can increase the width of your video without increasing the height... Yes. But you can't do it without distorting the video, by stretching it horizontally.

Comment: this is ok, can you please tell me how i can do this?

Comment: What tools (programs) do you have available? On what platform (Mac, Win etc)? With what codec is your video encoded?

Comment: I don't have nothing, I use windows 10

Comment: I try today find movie maker but not find official website

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to resizing the video.If you are using Windows platform you can use Windows movie maker to do it.Add your media file and switch to **Project Tab** you can set the ratio. only the two mentioned are available.
Wide Screen(16:9) & Standard(4:3)

If you are looking for a **fully customizable** Space,the free program recommended program is [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr)
.Download it,install and run the program.

- Choose the particular video clicking on the source button and navigate to it.
- Next choose the destination for the output
- Click on the picture tab and choose **None** from the *Anamorphic* dropdown list
- Then adjust your height and width (*Make sure you **untick** "keep aspect Ratio"*)
- Finally click **Start** then you will see the adjusted video in the folder you chose for the destination output.

Check the image:[image]

You can reduce the resolution too(Reducing resolution) with this tool.

Thats it, Enjoy:)